# How to create a summary table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given a table that lists actions of actors (I hide irrelevant timestamp column), we would like to have a summary table listing a row per actor with counts per action he did.
we have predefined three possible actions

Standard SQL or Google BigQuery Syntax

```
Actor   |   Action
_________________
Sam         shoot
Sam         shoot
Sam         heal
Sam         dead
Bob         shoot
Bob         shoot
Bob         shoot
Bob         dead
```

To

```
Actor   |  shoot  |  heal   | Dead
_____________________________________
Sam        2          1         1
Bob        3          0         1
```

Comment: What's expected to happen if someone later inserts the row (Bob, resurrected)?

Comment: 1. The summary should be created once we run the query...  

2. Assume we have predefined three possible actions only. shoot/head/dead

Comment: i would use more positive use case with something like `smile`, `happy`, etc.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant hhh I agree, I felt something wrong while writing the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the columns that you want, use `countif()`:

```
select actor,
       countif(action = 'shoot') as shoot,
       countif(action = 'heal') as heal,
       countif(action = 'dead') as dead
from t
group by actor;
```

If you don't, then you have a challenge, because SQL queries tend to need to know what columns are in the result set.  One workaround is to put the values in rows rather than columns:

```
actor    action     count
 sam     shoot        2
 . . .
```

That is:

```
select actor, action, count(*)
from t
group by actor, action;
```

(This does not include `0` counts, but the query can be adjusted fro this.)

Or to use JSON or arrays to store the values for every action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we have a predefined small set of actions (4). The given solution looks very neat and spot on, I'll test on our case.